# Digital Comparator from LSB to MSB using Lookahead

Tags: digital-logic, comparator, computer-architecture, homework, digital-comparator

This is homework to be upfront, but I'm really stuck on it and just need some kind of direction. I've been assigned to create a 16-bit lookahead comparator going from LSB to MSB using no more than 4-bit lookahead. The professor also said to remove the equals output and design the system so that when the two numbers are equal both less than and greater than will output '0'. I've been able to design the comparator, using a k-map, and defined the greater than and less than signals in their propagation forms., but I don't understand how the lookahead logic is supposed to work when going from LSB to MSB. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [image: Work Done so far]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Homework questions are ok ***if*** you show an attempt to solve the problem yourself. We need a diagram from you, or a schematic, or a logic chart.